# Google Play Developer Console - Uploading key password too weak

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

Trying to upload an Android application bundle I got the following error saying that the password I am using is not strong enough.

What does Google consider strong? Is there some place where I can check the strength of my passwords?

[image: Screen capture from Google Play Developer Console]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't complaining about a password, it is complaining about the signing key for your bundle. If I read the error correctly, it is complaining about the upload key.

The recommendations for upload key strengths [are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) in the section "create an upload key". It says:

> Upload key restrictions
>
> - The upload key must be an RSA key that's 2048 bits or more.
> - The following aren't supported: DSA keys, EC keys or RSA keys that are less than 2048 bits.

I suspect your upload key you are signing your app with is less than 2048 bits in size.

Comment: Can you let me know how can i check the key is weak while uploading.